# JNI, C++ problems

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I did an Opencv's application en windows and now I am using JNI to convert this code to Android but I am having some problems.
In concrete my native code not do nothing.

This is my Java class where I define my native methods:

```
package com.example.telo3;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Process {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativo");
    }

    public Process(){

        dir=inicializar_nativo();
    }

    public void Procesar(Mat framedetect, Mat framedraw){

        procesar_nativo(dir,framedetect.getNativeObjAddr(),framedraw.getNativeObjAddr());
    }


    private long dir;
    private static native long inicializar_nativo();
    private static native void procesar_nativo(long thiz, long framedetect, long framedraw);
```

}

This is my JNI code:

```
#include "nativo.h"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "FaceDetector.h"
#include "Draw.h"
#include "Almacena.h"
#include "Runnable.h"



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "NATIVO"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

struct variables {
    Almacena almacena;
    Draw draw;
    FaceDetector face_detector;
};

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_inicializar_1nativo(
        JNIEnv *, jobject) {

    long dir = (long) new variables();

    return (dir);


}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_procesar_1nativo(JNIEnv *,
        jobject, jlong dir, jlong framedetect, jlong framedraw) {



Mat* telo =(Mat*)framedetect;
Mat* telo2= (Mat*)framedraw;

((variables*)dir)->almacena = ((variables*)dir)->face_detector.Detect(*telo);


 //almacena = face_detector.Detect(frame_gray);


 ((variables*)dir)->draw.Dibujar(*telo2,((variables*)dir)->almacena);


 //frame_capturado = draw.Dibujar(frame_capturado, almacena);



if( (((variables*)dir)->almacena.get_faces()).size() ==0){

    LOGD("no detecto caras");
}


}
```

I think that I use the Jni correctly but the function Detect not works correctly because when I uses this if return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is `framedetect` 0? I made a test app based on this and it worked fine (that is, the jlong was converted to and from just fine, so that shouldn't be the issue).

Try catching the error with `ndk-gdb` to better understand the problem. Attaching it to the process might a problem though if it crashes straight away, in that case I like to put breakpoint on the java side before the crash, make the execution pause there using the debugger, attach `ndk-gdb` and continue let the java process continue.

Also I recommend using `reinterpret_cast<jlong>` and `reinterpret_cast<variables*>` instead of the C style casts, and save that cast to a separate variable to avoid casting all the time! cleaner code!